# Does the integral of a function exist at a sharp point in the function?

Tags: functions

This is a pretty basic and easy question to answer, but I am not certain about its answer (I am still studying at highschool).

Let's say we have a function with some sharp point and we want to find its improper integral, such as: f(x)=|1-x| (the answer will definitely imply defining the integral as a piece-wise function). Since there's a sharp point at x=1, would that value be included in the domain of the integral of the function?

The answer in my book to this exercise (and others which are almost the same) does include those values in the domain of the integral, but this doesn't make much sense, does it? On what grounds would that be the correct solution? I thought sharp points cannot possibly be derived nor integrated. I hope I have expressed my problem clearly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sharp points and points of discontinuity (jumps), as you say, cause trouble when differentiating but not generally when integrating.  Integration is a much more forgiving operation than differentiation and you will in time come to see a wide range of badly behaved functions that can be integrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fundamental difference between differentiation and integration is that differentiation is performed at specific points, while integration is done over a region. So while you are correct that a function cannot be differentiated at "sharp points" (more formally, points where the function is not differentiable), there is nothing to stop you from integrating *over* sharp points (so long as your function is integrable on whatever domain you're integrating over).

Though harder to actually compute, integration is, in a sense, nicer than differentiation. A differentiable function is necessarily continuous, but this is not the case for integrable functions - in fact, *any* continuous function is integrable. So even if you do have "sharp points", so long as your function is continuous (and even if it's not in pretty much every case you'll ever encounter in high school), you can integrate over any points at which your function isn't differentiable.

Practically, if your domain of integration includes the point $x=1$, then that just means you'll need to split up your integral. For example:
$$\int_0^2|1-x|\,dx=\int_0^1(1-x)\,dx+\int_1^2(x-1)\,dx.$$

Comment: Then, could we say that the domain of the integral is Df=R (the integral of f(x), I mean)? Would that be correct? It is hard for me to believe what you've said (I believe you, don't get me wrong). Considering that the primitive function of a function and its derivative are somehow linked, one would expect them to have the same domain (in this case they wouldn't, the domain of the derivative of f(x) would be Df=R-{1}). I know this is a really vague consideration, but that's how I think of it at the moment. Also, I wasn't refereing to a definite integral, I hope that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Indefinite integrals are really just a disguised form of definite integrals. $\int f(x)\,dx=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ for some constant $a$. And not necessarily. The Riemann integral is really only well-defined when you are integrating a bounded function over a bounded domain; you'll always get a function whose domain is your domain of integration when you do that. Things can go wrong when you change to improper integrals. Also, you might be interested in Volterra's function, an everywhere differentiable function with non-integrable derivative.